# Can I use Kaleo and other portlets from Liferay 6.1.0. in 6.1.1 version?

Tags: plugins, workflow, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

Can I use Kaleo and other portlets from Liferay 6.1.0. in 6.1.1 version.

I tried putting kaleo into 6.1.1 version's webapps and deploy directory, but nothing happened.

Am I required to modify the portlets to the new specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Liferay-plugins that are distributed by Liferay, they are typically only tested with the version they are compiled for - even though they might work, you are advised to use only 6.1.1 plugins with 6.1.1 installations. With regards to the data they have in the database, they're expected to be a smooth update/replacement. In case you have the impression that they work through release boundaries, it might be that you just didn't test enough corner cases.

Make your life easier by just using the same-version plugins

Comment: That sounds good enough,but is there any source available for getting plugins for 6.1.1,which have been removed since previous versions,rather than the marketplace

Comment: which ones are you looking for? Some might have been renamed, some might have been discontinued. At least kaleo (-web) that you specifically mention, is available in 6.1.1. You can also find others on github, tagged 6.1.1 at https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.1.1-ga2

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Wonderful answer. I included a link to your answer as the basis for answering another very [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13927972/468763).