# Liferay 6.1 portlet worked incorrect in 5.2.3

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have a portlet that worked fine on Liferay 6.1 portal but when I deploy it on Liferay 5.2.3
my configuration page did not even open.
How should I make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice authoritative [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13910680/468763) to a very similar question.

The portlets of newer versions are not designed to work on older installation of Liferay. Since they are compiled using the latest plugins-sdk and the also the different jars which have changed since the last version.

So if you want the newer version portlet to work with any older version then you have to compile the portlet with an older version of Liferay with that plugins-SDK. And I am sure there would be a lot of classes and jsp-tags in the Liferay 6.1 portlet which would not work in Liferay 5.2.3.

Comment: That means there is no way that I have a portlet which works on both 6.1 and 5.2.3 version?

Comment: Correct. Atleast won't work for the one & only WAR file. Though the source code may still work if you have taken care to include only those things which are there in both the versions. But would be too much of a hassle..

Comment: well, technically there is a way to have plugins that are compatible to all versions of Liferay - but that would be portlets that just use JSR-286 and no Liferay API at all. As soon as the API is used, the recommendation is to recompile and retest. Between major versions, I'd assume that it doesn't work out-of-the-box. Between minor versions you might be lucky, but remember, nobody ever checks this (see my answer that Prakash linked)